# Reading files into R

Tags: r, file-format

I have problems when reading a file of performance into R. Is there any example files so I know how to name the rows/columns? The data I have is; fund name (207), year, month and performance. I have saved the file as csv but R does´t seem to understand the format. Thanks in advance! /Johanna

Comment: The standard function to read csv files is `read.csv`. Did you try that?

Comment: Since you seem to be from Denmark, you might want to try `read.csv2` which uses the comma as decimal mark. If you want more help it is best if you paste the first few lines of your document in your question and add the code with which you tried to read the file.

Comment: Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I used read.csv and it worked but then R doesn't seem to understand what the file says. Its all just a mess. That´s why I wondered if there is any special way I need to sort my columns?

Comment: I used this; > read.csv("avkastning.csv",header=TRUE)
Any packages I need to download? 
Thanks! /Johanna

Answer (score 1):

Use following syntax:

```r
setwd("D:/Your Directory")
# Load CSV data
fund <- read.csv(
  file = "YourFile.csv",
  quote = "\"")

#Peek data
head(fund)
```